# Return a String value when method return type is Mono<String>

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, reactive-programming, project-reactor

My method returns a `Mono<String>` response back to the controller. However, I am getting the following `error` while trying to return a `String` value.

```
Required Type: Mono<String>, 
Provided: Mono<Object>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Mono<T> conforms to String inference variable R has incompatible bounds: equality constraints
```

**Service:**

```
public Mono<String> moveToDB(String pid, String op, MoveRequest moveRequest) {
        return Mono.just(pid)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(id -> persistenceService.withTransaction((s, em) -> {
                     //some code goes here
                    if (condition)
                       return "data sync failed"; //ERROR
                    return "data synced successfully"; //ERROR
        }));
}
```

I am new to reactive programming and I am probably making a silly mistake but I'd appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Reactive can be hard to learn indeed! It's hard to tell without having a bigger insight into the code. But I would say the issue is in the `.withTransaction` part. Perhaps you could separate that into another `.map()`. What is `withTransaction` actually? What does it accept and return?

Comment: `withTransaction()` is a method in another service to persist objects to the database. It accepts a lambda function and returns a `<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess method `withTransaction()` does not return `String` as it should. You should map the return value to a `String`:

```
.map(id -> service.withTransaction((s, em) -> {
    //some code goes here
    if (true)
        return "data sync failed";
    return "data synced successfully";
}))
.map(e -> e.toString()); //or whatever
```

Comment: if you're _sure_ `withTransaction` returns a `String` but are fighting the type system, `Flux#cast(String.class)` might be an option too